# Python, function wrapping while keeping its reference or, add positional argument dynamically?

Tags: python, python-3.x, wrapper

I'm a big Python noob and having some problem with using `pyglet.clock.schedule_once()` function.

```
Environments;

python==3.10.6
pyglet==2.0.dev18
```

Please don't focus on pyglet. My question is, is there a proper way to wrap a function other than with functools.wraps, or other ways to add its argument to a function when it is passed to something.

The pyglet schedule functions need a function object with a mandatory positional argument('dt', should be in first position) but I don't wanna add it into every function codes I've written.

```
delay = 1.0

def foo(arg1):
    print(arg1)

pyglet.clock.schedule_once(foo, delay, 'hello')

>> error : foo() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given

def bar(dt, arg1):
    print(arg1)

pyglet.clock.schedule_once(bar, delay, 'hello')

>> hello    ### it works. but should add 'dt' to all functions.
```

So my humble attempt was make a wrapper.

```py
import functools

scheduled_functions = []
''' simple replacement of pyglet.clock module '''

def schedule_once(func, delay, *args, **kwargs):
    ''' simple replacement of pyglet.clock.schedule_once '''
    print('scheduled func :',func)
    scheduled_functions.append(func)

def unschedule(func):
    ''' simple replacement of pyglet.clock.unschedule '''
    print('try to unschedule ', func)
    if func in scheduled_functions:
        scheduled_functions.remove(func)
    else:
        print(func, 'not found')

def delay_run(delay:float, func, *args, **kwargs):
    ''' my wrapper for add an argument(dt) to func '''
    if not isinstance(delay, (float, int)): return False
    if delay <= 0: return func(*args, **kwargs)
    
    @functools.wraps(func)
    def _wrapper(dt, func, *args, **kwargs):
        return func(*args, **kwargs)
    
    schedule_once(_wrapper, delay, *args, **kwargs)


class Foo:    
    def destroy(self):
        print('destroy ', self)


f = Foo()
delay_run(1, f.destroy)
unschedule(f.destroy)
```

And the result is below;

```bash
scheduled func : <function Foo.destroy at 0x7f7f3b1a32e0>
try to unschedule  <bound method Foo.destroy of <__main__.Foo object at 0x7f7f39fc9b40>>
<bound method Foo.destroy of <__main__.Foo object at 0x7f7f39fc9b40>> not found
```

Yeah. The reference of `f.destroy` is `<bound method Foo.destroy>` but wrapped `f.destroy` turns to `<function Foo.destroy>` reference so it can't be unscheduled.

Of course without `@functools.wraps()` shows,

```bash
scheduled func : <function delay_run.<locals>._wrapper at 0x7fe9180ef2e0>
```

So, I need the other way to wrap a function or, some trick for adding positional argument into an existing function object instance. ...But not sure it's mutable

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

In Python, in order to wrap a function, we use a decorator. You've already used one yourself: `functools.wraps`. A decorator is a function that accepts a function as an argument, and returns a modified function. In your case, it would be this, to add the `dt` parameter:

```py
import functools

def add_dt(func):
    @functools.wraps(func)
    def _wrap(dt, *args, **kwargs):
        return func(*args, **kwargs)
    return _wrap
```

We then use it like this:

```py
@add_dt
def foo(arg1):
    print(arg1)

delay = 1
pyglet.clock.schedule_once(foo, delay, "hello") # It works!
```